# Does a p5.js based website require windows hosting?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, web-development-server

does my application of the p5.js library require me to have my website on a windows server instead of a linux hosting server? Or can I have linux hosting without any major issues or anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can host your p5.js on Linux, Windows or Mac OSX server or for many things you can even just run your scripts from your local machine.. take a look at this  [tutorial](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server) for more info.

> Some functionality (loading external files, for example) works as expected when the files are placed online via FTP or SSH. However, if you try to view them locally, you see some kind of "cross-origin" errors in console. The solution to this is to view them using what's called a local web server. This tutorial includes instructions for setting up several types of local web servers on each of Mac OSX, Windows, and Linux.